# Power BI dumping/printing variable in Python Visual script

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

### Introduction

I am using Power BI desktop and noticed some limitations on the pre-made graph models like the Line Graph. That's why I am trying to make a graph using Python Visuals. I am familiar with Python but I am not familiar with the Python Visual module in Power BI. Currently I am trying to make a simple Line Graph with this module.

### I verified that I can draw a graph using Python Visuals (using matplotlib.pyplot) with some of my variables

```
# dataset = pandas.DataFrame(User field, Tag, Value, Resultaat, Timestamp)
# dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = dataset.Timestamp
y = dataset.Value

plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

[image: working graph with some variables]

### However I am unable to plot some of my variables

For example I have the following two variables:

- User field (timestamp)
- Resultaat (int)

And I want to plot these two values.

```
x = dataset['User Field']
y = dataset.Resultaat

plt.plot(x, y, 'ro')
plt.show()
```

Unfortunately the code shown above does not create a working graph. I want to know what is going wrong. That's why I would like to print the variable dataset['User field'].

### Question

- Is it possible to debug a value in Python Visuals? Can I dump/print a variable like print(dataset['User field']) to see if the data of this variable is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to print the values in the Python editor in Power BI. However it's possible to edit the code that is used Power BI in an **external editor**.
[image]

When clicking on the export button a Python script is being generated and automatically opened in your default editor for Python files. All the variables from Power BI are exported to a CSV file. The automatically generated Python script reads these values.

Because a Python script is generated and can be used outside of Power BI all the Python functionalities can be used. **This includes printing variables.**

```
# Prolog - Auto Generated #
import os, matplotlib.pyplot, uuid, pandas

os.chdir(u'C:/Users/Fakeuser/PythonEditorWrapper_886e059e-ab5c-423e-a20b-a224ee311990')
dataset = pandas.read_csv('input_df_d776f9db-be3f-4120-90f8-d9abe5c31964.csv')
matplotlib.pyplot.figure(figsize=(5.55555555555556,4.16666666666667))
matplotlib.pyplot.show = lambda args=None,kw=None: matplotlib.pyplot.savefig(str(uuid.uuid1()))

# dataset = pandas.DataFrame(User field, Tag, Value, Resultaat, Timestamp)
# dataset = dataset.drop_duplicates()

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

tags = set(dataset['Tag'])
print(tags)
```